Handling multiple forms in same table in react
Building a form input in table format which can contain multiple row, it needs to store the value of inputs of multiple rows in array as an object(educations as shown in code).
I am having difficulty in storing respective data in educations array as per the index of education
How to approach this problem? and how is it done?
const AddEducationDetails: React.FC = () => {
  const [showLevel, setShowLevel] = useState("upto 10");
  const [educations, setEducations] = useState<Education[]>([
    {
      level: "",
      studiedCourse: "",
      studiedAt: "",
      studiedFrom: "",
      passedYear: "",
      board: "",
      university: "",
      file: "",
    },
  ]);

  const handleInputChange = () => {};

  const handleLevelSelection = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>,
    index: number,
  ) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setShowLevel(value);
    console.log(index);
  };
  return (

      <table className="min-w-full overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-[#373747]">
        //thead
        <tbody>
          {educations.map((education, index) => (
            <tr key={index} className="border border-gray-600">
              <td className="px-4 py-2">
                <select
                  name="level"
                  onChange={(e) => handleLevelSelection(e, index)}
                  className="mb-4 w-[110px] flex-1 rounded-md border-0 bg-gray-700 p-2 text-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-blue-500"
                >
                  <option value="upto 10">Upto 10</option>
                  <option value="+2">+2</option>
                  <option value="above +2">Above +2</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td className="px-4 py-2">
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  value={education.studiedCourse}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
              </td>
             //multiple td with form inputs 
 
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
  );
};



Use Object.keys(education) to retrieve the keys of each field to handle multiple fields with a single  component.
Pass the key to the name attribute of each  to identify which field has changed.
In the onChange event, pass both (event, index) to determine the field and the index of the education object it belongs to.
Extract event.target.name and event.target.value from the event to get the field name and the new value.
Copy the educations array using the spread operator (...), then create a new array and update the object at the specified index.
Use the index to update the specific field of the object within the copied array.
Finally, pass the updated array to the setEducations function to update the state.

What needs to be fixed

